# Como puedo centrar un texto dentro de un foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, css3

tengo textos que necesito centrar pero el problema es que los textos tienen diferente longitud y yo los posiciono directamente con css
por ejemplo.. en la monedas pueden aparecer 1000 y en otra moneda solo 40.. y no puedo centrar por separado ya que ambos estan en un bucle..
[image: Imagen]

Como se puede observar la moneda que tiene 40 y la que tiene 100 no estan centrados correctamente
hay alguna forma de hacer esto?
mi css

```
 .posicion_texto_de_circulo {
    position: absolute;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    top: 20%;
    left: 14%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

mi codigo

`<div class="row">
@foreach($catalogos as $c)
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img width="200" class="casi_circulo" src="{{asset('imagenes/productos/'.$c->image)}}" alt="">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$c->id}}" href="#" class="btn btn_catalogo poll-name" class="">{{$c->name}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img width="200" src="{{asset('front/css/moneda.png')}}" alt="">
            <h2 class="posicion_texto_de_circulo rotar"><b>{{$c->price}}</b><h2>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$c->id}}" href="#" class="btn btn_catalogo2">CANJEAR CARSANIES</a>
        </div>
@endforeach
</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-align` Establece la alineación del contenido de un elemento de bloque:

**Valores permitidos:**

- left
- right
- center
- justify
- inherit

Puedes probar con esto tu css con esto:

```
.posicion_texto_de_circulo {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    top: 20%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

O también:

```
.posicion_texto_de_circulo {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    top: 20%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Para tener más claro el concepto puedes revisar esta [Documentación](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/referencia-css2/text-align)
Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Buenas.. gracias por responder... con tu codigo lo que hace es lo manda para un costado y todos empiezan desde la misma posicion... yo lo que necesito es que el texto aparezca centrado en la moneda sin importar si el numero es 40 o 1000

Comment: ¿Si colocaste el **width: 100%;** ?

Comment: No.. ahora lo agregue, pero el numero sale de la moneda. Afectara si lo posicion con `left: 20%;`??

Comment: agregue al codigo `left: -20%;` y al parecer funciona bien!

Comment: Excelente amigo, me alegra que haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @dnlb Yo creo que debes de cambiar la redacción en esto "text-align Establece la alineación del contenido de un elemento de bloque.", ya que no siempre se da el caso, si metes elementos de bloque dentro de elementos de bloque, no quedarán alineados con `text-align`, en el problema se dio el caso de que fue correcto porque el texto del `<h2>` termina siendo un elemento en línea, entonces más bien sería que cualquier elemento quedará alineado con la propiedad `text-align` del padre si los hijos de este son `inline` o `inline-block`.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu comentario, sería de gran ayuda que editaras mi respuesta y yo te apruebo la edición. ¡Feliz día!